# How to remove ad-type.google.com pop ups from **PC**? (Tradeadexchange redirection.)

Tags: google-chrome, internet, virus, popups, adware

Okay, it seems that my router is infected. Whichever device I connect with my router, gets this pop ups. I remember, I managed to free atleast my PC, of this virus. But it again has come back and irritates and annoys me so much. Is there a long term solution? 
***Everytime I click something, even if it is a button, a text field or nothing at all (on the page), the pop up appears.***

Comment: Please dont mark questions duplicate just like that. This question is specifically for a malware that is annoying people so much today. @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303.

Comment: Read, I had seen this question already before. But nothing helped.

Comment: ok friend lets consider  your router might be infected ,kindly post the routers dns server snapshot?sometimes dns server might cause the issue,if router is infected **solutions might be a)check ur dns settings ,b)download the recent firmware of router and reset the router** sample :http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/network-wifi/how-connect-your-router-change-settings-3515634/

Comment: Can I contact my ISP to change my DNS server? @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303.

Comment: does the ads occur only at google chrome?could u post the sample ad which appears ,if its browser based u could restrict it through addon,if its windows based u could block it through firewall

Comment: I got my solution! I changed my DNS to google's. Thank you! And as far as the ad link is concerned. http://ad-type.google.com/rot.aspx?partner=910345&f=popup-u http://www.tradeadexchange.com/a/display.php?r=425636 @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303.

Comment: if it worked feel free to write up as answer which might help other users in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to "change adapter settings" and then to properties for your router. Then click on "IPv4" properties and change the DNS to preferred one "8.8.8.8" (Google's Server). It will solve the problem!

Comment: no it didnt solve the problem

Comment: It is only for PC. And very **rarely** you will get the pop ups, and those too won't load, "Error was not resolved" etc. errors would come.